# Get epoch timestamp in Grunt JS

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I found in the Grunt docs how to format a date in the template:

```
grunt.template.today('yyyy') // '2014'
```

from http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template

I'm wondering how I can get the epoch.  I'm using a text-replace plugin to update a global variable when the files were last changed (using grunt-contrib-watch).

Just not sure how to update the variable with a proper epoch timestamp.

Without a format, template.today does a standard:

```
Wed Apr 09 2014 13:21:03
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that Grunt is just Javascript, you can use:

```
new Date().getTime();
```

This will give you the epoch time. Just assign to a variable and pass to the text-replace plugin.

Comment: No worries! Sometimes the answer is just a lot more simple than we think.

Comment: Even better, use `Date.now()` so you don't unnecessarily create and then discard a `Date` instance.